# How to find if a GPS coordinate lies on a specific road

Tags: python, gps, openstreetmap

Is there a way to get all road of an area, and then find out if a GPS coordinate is on a specific road. Something like:

```
all_driveable_road_in_NY = [id1, id2, id3, ..., idn] //Where idi represents the road number i
gps_coordj = [lat1, lat2]

for p in range(0, len(all_driveable_road_in_NY):
    if gps_coordj on road all_driveable_road_in_NY[p]:
        print("gps on road : " + all_driveable_road_in_NY[p])
```

How could man do that in python using openstreetmap? 
Any hints will be welcome.
Thanks

Comment: if you have a shapefile of the road or you have a polygon for the road mapped, you can use pyton `shapely` and check if two polygons intersect or not. [link on polygon intersection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90055/finding-if-two-polygons-intersect-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

A linear search by road name is not appropriate for this problem. For example, we don't need to search all roads in the Bronx to find a location in Manhattan. Instead swap the search criteria.

Suppose we have a large database of (road, lat long) corresponding to a point on each road every x meters. We have many data points for each road. Rather than searching all existing roads, we can search for the closest location. Any database can index these points for faster searches, probably using some sort of tree under the hood for O(log(n)) searches rather than O(n).

It's the same technique you would use when searching a word in a dictionary (like the book. okay maybe you would just use google, but hear me out). To find 'hello', you would first open the book halfway and see you are at 'R'. Now you know you only need to search the front half of the book, not the entire book. In the same way, we order the lat, long points to help us search faster.

Unless you are running this database, it will need to be supported by your API. This sounds like a common use case, so it's likely that it is supported.